# Representable numbers in binary system but not in decimal system

Tags: numerical-methods

I need some advices to solve this problem.

> What numbers are representable with a finite expression in the binary system but are not representable in the decimal system?

What I've tried is to find numbers of the form $x = q \times 2^m$ which can not be written as $x = r \times 10^n$, but I feel I'm not doing anything making this assumption.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might want to take a look here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/237014/are-there-numbers-that-are-not-representable-in-base-10-but-can-be-represented-i . This applies to comp sci mainly, but you get the pattern.

Comment: I don't think such numbers exist. The integer part of any finite number is representable with a finite number of digits in both systems, so only the fractional part is of interest. Any number that requires $n$ fractional digits in the binary system will also require $n$ fractional digits in the decimal system (e.g. $0.11_2 = 0.75_{10}$), but the converse is not true, e.g. $0.1_{10}$ is not expressible as a finite number of binary digits.

Comment: Note that $q\times 2^{-m}$ with $m>0$ and $q\in\mathbb Z$ equals $5^mq\times 10^{-m}$

Comment: None, because $2\mid10$.